# Somehow end up with a Promise<Either<Errors, Job>> instead of TaskEither<Errors, Job>

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I'm not really comfortable with FP-TS just yet (or functional programming in general), so I may be doing some things wrong here.

I have the following function where I'd like to return a `TaskEither<Errors, Job>` but I can't seem to get it to work.

This one returns `Promise<Either<Errors, Job>>`

```js
export function storeJob(job: CreateJob): TaskEither<Errors, Job> {
  const dto = toCreateDto(job)
  const insertQuery = createInsertQuery('jobs')(dto)

  return pipe(
      insertQuery, // string
      query, // TaskEither<Error, unknown>
      fromEither(fromDto(dto) // Either<Errors, Job> ) // TaskEither<Errors, Job> 
  ) // Promise<Either<Errors, Job>>
}
```

Another try (only changed the last pipe, added `map`) I did returns `TaskEither<Error, TaskEither<Errors, Job>>`

```js
export function storeJob(job: CreateJob): TaskEither<Errors, Job> {
  const dto = toCreateDto(job)
  const insertQuery = createInsertQuery('jobs')(dto)

  return pipe(
      insertQuery, // string
      query, // TaskEither<Error, unknown>
      map(() => fromEither(fromDto(dto) // Either<Errors, Job> ))
  ) // TaskEither<Error, TaskEither<Errors, Job>>
}
```

For the second one after that, adding a `flatten` after the map doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Please share the types of `toCreateDto`, `createInsertQuery`, `query` and `fromDto`.

Comment: I've added the types in the comments after the specific items. I didn't for the first two, `toCreateDto` and `createInsertQuery`, since I don't think those types are relevant here. Since the first item in the pipe is the output of that and is a string.

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess I was (am?) confused by the annotations because `pipe` expects a function as the second argument but gets a `TaskEither`.

Comment: Ah right, yeah, that was a function indeed that returns that type. (it accepts the string above). But I think I've solved it. One of the functions I call returns an array of Errors on the left, while one in there also returns only one Error.

Comment: `TaskEither<A, B>` is just an alias for `() => Promise<Either<A, B>>` - so if you are seeing `Promise<Either<A, B>>` somewhere it means that you are "executing" a TaskEither by calling it prematurely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems that in the question. One of the `left` values in the pipe was `Error` and the other was `Errors`. Which means there were two paths where different left values could be returned. To make it more clear. I changed the Errors into a type `ValidationErrors`. And used `chainW` to be able to merge multiple left errors in one pipe. Resulting in eventually having:

```js
export function storeJob(job: CreateJob): TaskEither<Error | ValidationErrors, Job> {
  const dto = toCreateDto(job)
  const insertQuery = createInsertQuery('jobs')(dto)

  return pipe(
      insertQuery,
      query,
      T.chainW(() => T.fromEither(fromDto(dto)))
  )
}
```